# print every 4 columns to one row in perl or awk

Tags: perl, awk

would you please help me how to convert every 4-sequantial rows into one tab-separated column?

convert:

```
A
1
2
3
3
3
4
1
```

to :

```
A   1  2  3
3   3  4  1
```

Comment: what does **one tab-separated column** mean? e.g. `A<TAB>1<space>2<space>3`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to use `xargs`:

```
$ xargs -n4 < file
A 1 2 3
3 3 4 1
```

With `awk` you would do:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s",$0,(NR%4?FS:RS)}' file
A 1 2 3
3 3 4 1
```

Another flexible approach is to use `pr`:

```
$ pr -tas' ' --columns 4 file
A 1 2 3
3 3 4 1
```

---

Both the `awk` and `pr` solution can be easily modified to change the output separator to a `TAB`:

```
$ pr -at --columns 4 file
A         1         2             3
3         3         4             1                        

$ awk '{printf "%s%s",$0,(NR%4?OFS:RS)}' OFS='\t' file
A         1         2             3
3         3         4             1
```

Comment: Also `paste - - - - file` and `-d` to set the separator char.

Comment: @glennjackman only problem is it doesn't scale.. I wonder if an elegant way exist to generate n `-` dynamically, I don't think one does?

Comment: I guess you could do `n=5 cols=$(printf -- "-%d " $(seq $n) | tr -d '[:digit:]'); paste $cols file`

Answer (score 3):

```
$ perl -pe 's{\n$}{\t} if $. % 4' old.file > new.file
```

or simply (thanks to mpapec's comment):

```
$ perl -pe 'tr_\n_\t_ if $. % 4' old.file > new.file
```

Comment: I guess anchoring is not needed, so just `y|\n|\t| ..`