# converting four columns to two using linux commands

Tags: bash, awk, sed, xargs

I am wondering how one could merge four columns into two in the following manner (using the awk command, or other possible commands).

For example,

Old:

```
A B C D 
E F G H
I J K L 
M N O P 
.
.
.
```

New:

```
A B 
C D 
E F
G H  
I J  
K L  
M N  
O P 
.  
.
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20608501/print-every-4-columns-to-one-row-in-perl-or-awk

Answer (score 2):

That's actually quite easy with `awk`, as per the following transcript:

```
pax> cat inputFile
A B C D
E F G H

pax> awk '{printf "%s %s\n%s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4}' <inputFile
A B
C D
E F
G H
```

Answer (score 2):

Hww about using `xargs` here? Could you please try following once.

```
xargs -n 2 < Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
A B
C D
E F
G H
I J
K L
M N
O P
```

Answer (score 1):

with GNU `sed`

```
$ sed 's/ /\n/2' file
```

replace 2nd space with new line.